# Cross-classes manipulations of objects in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make a simple library OOP program in Python.Here is the structure:

class Books(object) with attributes

```
class Books(object):
    book_id=""
    book_title=""
    Books=[book_id,book_title]
def __init__(self,book_id,book_title):
    self.book_id = book_id
    self.book_title = book_title

#Books=[book_id,book_title]
book2= Books('1504231','Murders')
print(book1.__str__())
```

class BookList(Books) with objects of created by class Books

```
class BookList(Books):
    def __init__(self):
        self.listbook = []
 book_list= BookList()
 book_list.add_book_object(book2)
 book_list.show_books()
```

(Operations in this scope works for me good)

class Users(object) with attributes (Similar def and init as for Books)

```
user1= Users ('adfelko','Adam')
print(user1.__str__())
```

class UserList(Users) with objects of created by class Users (Similar def and init as for BookList)

```
user_list= UserList()
user_list.add_user_object(user1)
user_list.show_users()
```

(Operations in this scope works for me good)

Now, I am trying to create actual Lease class, which will hold dictionary of objects(each object=each lease, each leases = [users object, books object])

This is my try:

```
#Definition of class Leases 
class Leases(Users,Books):
#Set constructor
    def __init__(self,user,book):
        self.leases = [user,book]
    #Create a lease       
    def borrow_book_to_user(self,u_name,t_book):
        user=u_name
        book=t_book
        lease = [user,book]
        self.leases.append(lease)
    
    #Show lease
    def __str__(self):
        print(self)
```

Maybe I have a bad concept of using it, not sure, but I should probably not go through lists- BookList and UserList ?
Or how I should I get it connected and be able to call functions of the previous classes?
The thing for now works:

```
lease= Leases(user1,book2)
lease.__str__()
```

But the output looks something like this:

```
[<__main__.Users object at 0x0000010E69BFE280>, <__main__.Books object at 0x0000010E69BFE1F0>]
```

I would like to get direct out put like:

```
[ ['adfelko','Adam'],['1504231','Murders'] ]
```

With possibility to get access and change the attributes of this Users or Books object from Leases class, is someone able to help here please ?
Thanks
Best Regards
UPDATE:
@guimoute Thank you for your comment! It did not help to resolve, but helped me to understand more in depth.

I had to rethink my usage of Leases class(other stuff stay same):

```
#Definition of class leases 
class Leases():
#Set constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.leases = []   
    #Create lease object    
    def add_lease_object(self,user,book):
        lease = { user : book}
        self.leases.append(lease)
    #Create lease object    
    def del_lease_object(self,user,book):
        lease = { user : book}
        self.leases.remove(lease)

    #Show lease
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.leases)
    #Show leases
    def show_leases(self):
        for l in self.leases:
            #print(vars(l))
            #json.dump(l,str)
            print(l.__str__())
```

And I am executing:

```
lease= Leases()
lease.add_lease_object(user1,book2)
#print(lease.__str__())
print("*************************")
lease.show_leases()
print("*************************")
lease.add_lease_object(user2,book3)
print("*************************")
lease.show_leases()
print("*************************")
lease.del_lease_object(user2,book3)
print("*************************")
lease.show_leases()
```

Which seems to be working right, but again it is not showing output of nested objects as a string values:

```
{<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98E250>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD8F2EB0>}

{<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98E250>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD8F2EB0>} {<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98ED90>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD98E1F0>}

{<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98E250>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD8F2EB0>}
```

As you can see above I have tried even:

```
    #print(vars(l))
    #json.dump(l,str)
```

But similar result when trying to access nested object of different class. Do you have any better idea please ? Thank you

Comment: Well, change `print(self)` to `print(self.leases)`. Also you're supposed to return the string value in `__str__` not print it.

Answer (score 0):

The ouptut you see:

```
{<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98E250>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD8F2EB0>} {<main.Users object at 0x000001F9BD98ED90>: <main.Books object at 0x000001F9BD98E1F0>}
```

Is the default text representation of your instances of Users and Books. If you want it to display differently, you just have to override the `__str__` method in both of these classes:

```
class Books(object):
    [...]
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}, {}".format(self.book_id, self.book_title)
```

Now, when you directly (like with `str(book1)`) or indirectly call for a textual reprensentation of your Book and similarly User objects, your `__str__` methods will be used instead of the default one.